# Trouble after Upgrade SQL Server version and have two server now in services.msc

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express, sql-server-2016-express

*I'm a beginner in this, I've been searching for long on internet. But as many solution in internet, I don't understand as much i wanted. And I have some question to for resolution. I see a place the recommend to ask some like this as Super User, but I recently just started using 'Stack Overflow' so I don't know How To Use Super User.*

Start when I download a new setup of SQL Server 2016 and choose option to 'Upgrade-from-previous-version', from process I see, it just added 2 features. 
**From what I really want is to change entirely my SQL server from 2014 to 2016.**
 [Two Server in services.msc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLYWi.jpg)

So i try to do option 'basic-installation' from installer and it work honestly but provide 2 server which server 2016 and 2014.
Maybe I can just uninstall the server 2014, and get work with 2016 instead. But Can I bring my database in 2014 too?, I mean it has compatibility-problem.

And it don't have SQL Server Management Studio so I download a newest version of it (v18.00)

[Two server with different SQL Server version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gye4.jpg)

My question is =

1. Can I keep my database in server 2014, my database in 2016 is empty (did I must attach it again)?
2. Did it just OK to have two Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?
3. Why I don't get MSSMS when I install SQL Server 2016?
4. If I must do Question1, How To Upgrade my database to version 2016?
5. Is it bad for my laptop to having two Version of SQL Server, or I must delete one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Backup and restore to 2016 (or keep it in 2014)
2. Yes, but not necessary, just use latest version, uninstall older
3. Management Studio can be downloaded separately
4. See (1)
5. No, both can be kept, but remember that both services will be running which may impact performance and resource usage. You can stop these services using SQL Server Configuration Manager

Comment: Thank for answering

Comment: No problem. If you're happy with my answer, please mark it as the correct answer.